# Word similar to chic/exotic in sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-choice

Word or phrase to suit the highlighted part better? Also is 'chicness' correctly used here?

> Intrigued by `the chicness/exoticity of` her rugs, I was
>   lucky to meet her.

Comment: what about seduction ? it is blatantly direct ! :)

Comment: Intricacy. Elegance. Voguishness. _Chicness_ is ok, _exoticity_ isn't.